# Quelle différence entre « personne » et « plus personne » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, négation

Cette question fait suite à cette réponse magistrale de Yves la France :

> Le y dans "s'y connaître" a donc remplacé le "à/en quelque chose" de la tournure originale, que pour ainsi dire **plus personne** n'emploie aujourd'hui.

De [la page 109 de Biographie universelle par Louis Gabriel Michaud](http://books.google.com/books?id=GwUJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA109&dq=%22que+plus+personne%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=ovzhUoOMGIOqkQWI_4GAAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22que%20plus%20personne%22&f=false) :

> Or que pouvaient faire en ces moments suprêmes d'un nouveau règne ces vieux causeurs qui n'avaient su que parler toute leur vie ? Il fallut se taire; et Fiévée et plusieurs autres avec lui avaient la sagesse et l'esprit de ne plus rien dire aussitôt qu'ils eurent compris définitivement que **plus personne** ici-bas n'était disposé à les écouter.

Pourquoi pas simplement « *personne* » dans les deux cas ? J'ai beau me référer à [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/forumtitles/plus+personne).

Cette proposition diffère-t-elle de la négation : personne + ne + verbe conjugué + plus ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On utilise "plus personne" pour souligner une évolution dans le temps, tandis que "personne" est juste une négation sans référence temporelle.  C'est en effet équivalent à "personne + ne + verbe conjugué + plus" (le sens est le même).

> Plus personne ne parle araméen de nos jours.  C'est bien une langue morte.
>
> En 2100, plus personne ne mourra du cancer.

Comment: Vivement 2100 ! (Ou bien veut-ce dire que... tout le monde sera *déjà* mort avant cette date ? Oh la la...)

Comment: +1. J'ajouterais pour les anglophones : le "plus" fonctionne ici comme "no longer" en anglais. Par exemple, "no one does that any longer" (ou "anymore"). C'est le cas maintenant, mais ce n'etait pas le cas auparavant...

Answer (score 4):

La nuance entre *personne* et ***plus*** personne est celle qu'il y a entre ***pas*** maintenant et ***plus*** maintenant.

*Personne* fait référence à la situation d'aujourd'hui; *plus personne* fait référence à la situation d'aujourd'hui, qui n'est plus la même que celle du passé.

Où en est-on de l'exploration de Jupiter ?"

- *Personne* ne s'y intéresse. Ça n'intéresse *personne* (*aujourd'hui* ça n'intéresse personne).
- ***Plus*** personne ne s'y intéresse. Ça n'intéresse ***plus*** personne (dans le passé ça intéressait les gens, mais ce n'est *plus le cas aujourd'hui*).